# inserting pdf in latex is always putting me the first page

Tags: pdf, latex, pdflatex

I can't insert my whole PDF file in latex. My file is 18 pages long, and my code just repeats the first page in my document 18 times.

Here is what I currently have:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}  
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace} 
\usepackage{times}  
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}
\section*{blabla}
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={}]{file.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show the .log file?

Comment: here it is : https://pastebin.com/ZcFZbmbF

Comment: Thanks for the log file! I don't see any obvious problems, so I can only guess where the problem might come from. 1) maybe it is worth a try to rename `fiche_ecandidat.pdf` to `fiche-ecandidat.pdf` (sometimes special characters like _ can cause problems in file names) 2) Your tex distribution is not up-to-date. I tested the code from your question with texlive 2019 and it works for me, but I don't know if this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, indeed changing the name did not overcome the probleme but using the latest version of Texshop did... Unfortunately it seems that my Biblatex bibliography is not compatible with this application... I will try something else

Comment: If you could make a minimal working example of your problem with the bibliography, I could take a look

Comment: Thank you so much, I am lost one more time if you mind have a look: https://pastebin.com/3UWis6gJ

Comment: Try to delete the `.bbl`, `.blg` and `.bcf` files, then compile again with `pdflatex->biber->pdflatex->pdflatex`. If his does not help, please make a short example .tex document that reproduces your problem.